# Propositional calculus logic question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In my assignment I have the following question:

> For every proposition $\theta$ let $E(\theta)$ be the set of basic propositions.
> Prove the following:
>
> For every two propositions,  $\alpha$ and  $\beta$ such that $\alpha$
> is not a contradiction and $\beta$ is not a tautology,
> if $\alpha \Rightarrow\beta$ then a proposition $\gamma$ exists such that:
> $\alpha \Rightarrow\gamma$ and $\gamma \Rightarrow \beta$ such that
> $$E(\gamma)\subseteq E(\alpha) \cap E(\beta)$$

I know the answer is related to DNF, but I can't quite understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Take a look at the edits I made to your post. Your LaTeX was a little off, but you were on the right track :)

Comment: @graydad Thank you! I have now made the final fix, your help is great!

Answer (score 2):

Form the original paper of William Craig :

- [Three Uses of the Herbrand-Gentzen Theorem in Relating Model Theory and Proof Theory](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2963594?uid=2134&uid=3738296&uid=378508351&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=378508341&uid=60&sid=21104605022381), *The Journal of Symbolic Logic*, Vol. 22, No. 3 (Sep.1957), pp. 269-285 :

The context of Craig's paper is a generalization of E.W.Beth's work on the first-order notion of *definability*.

> [Beth's result] may be interpreted as showing that [...] the expressive power of each first-order system is rounded out, or the system is *functionally complete*, in the following sense : any functional relationship which obtains between concepts that are expressible in the system is itself expressible and provable in the system.

Craig states the lemma as :

> a useful tool for [investigating] how is a certain modeltheoretic property of a system reflected by theorems in the system.

---

See Raymond Smullyan, [First-Order Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486683702) (1968), **Ch.XV : Craig's Interpolation Lemma and Beth's Definability Theorem**, page 127-on :

> A formula $Z$ is called an interpolation formula for a formula $X \rightarrow Y$ if all predicates and parameters of $Z$ occur both in $X$ and in $Y$, and if 
>   $X \rightarrow Z, Z \rightarrow Y$ are both valid. Craig's celebrated Interpolation lemma 
>   says that for any valid sentence $X \rightarrow Y$ : *(i)* if $X, Y$ have at least one 
>   predicate in common, then there exists an interpolation sentence for $X \rightarrow Y$; *(ii)* if $X, Y$ have no predicates in common, then either $Y$ is valid or $X$ is unsatisfiable.
>
> We will now adjoin the propositional constants $\top, \bot$ to our language , and so case *(ii)* can be subsumed under case *(i)* as follows. If $Y$ is valid, then $X \rightarrow \top$, $\top \rightarrow Y$ are both valid, so then $\top$ is an interpolation formula for $X \rightarrow Y$. If $X$ is unsatisfiable, then $X \rightarrow \bot$, $\bot \rightarrow Y$ are both valid, so then $\bot$ is an interpolation formula for $X \rightarrow Y$.
>
> There is a corresponding interpolation lemma for propositional logic: If $X \rightarrow Y$ is a tautologous formula of propositional logic, then there exists a formula $Z$ (again called an interpolation formula for $X \rightarrow Y$) of propositional logic such that all propositional variables of $Z$ occur in $X$ and in $Y$ and such that $X \rightarrow Z$, $Z \rightarrow Y$ are both tautologies. [For example, $q$ is an interpolation formula for $(p \land q) \rightarrow (p \lor q)$.]

[...]

> One important use of Craig's Interpolation Lemma is that it yields a remarkably elegant proof of Beth's Definability Theorem which we now discuss.
>
> Let $P, P_1, \ldots, P_n$ be the predicates which occur in [a first-order *theory*] $A$, and let us presently assume that P is of [arity] one. $P$ is said to be *explicitly* definable from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ in the theory $A$ if there exists a formula $\varphi(x)$ with just one free variable $x$, whose predicates are all in the set $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ (so $P$ is not a predicate of $\varphi(x)$) and such that
>
> $$A \vdash (\forall x) [P(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)],$$
>
> and such a formula $\varphi(x)$ is said to constitute an *explicit* definition of $P$ from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ in the theory $A$.
>
> Now we say that the axioms of $A$ *implicitly* define $P$ from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ or that $P$ is *implicitly* definable from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ in the theory $A$ if the following condition holds: Take a [unary] predicate $P'$ which does not occur in $A$, and let $A'$ be the result of substituting $P'$ for $P$ in every element of $A$. Then $P$ is called implicitly definable from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ in $A$ if
>
> $$A \cup A' \vdash (\forall x) [P(x) \leftrightarrow P'(x)].$$
>
> Using the completeness theorem, this condition is equivalent to the condition that any two interpretations of $P_1, \ldots, P_n, P$ which satisfy $A$ and which agree on $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ must also agree on $P$ - or stated otherwise, given any values of $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ there is at most one value of $P$ which satisfies the axioms of $A$.
>
> It is obvious that if $A$ defines $P$ explicitly from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ then it defines $P$ implicitly from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$. For suppose $P$ is explicitly definable 
>   from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ in $A$. Then we have $A \vdash (\forall x) [P(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)]$. Then of course, we also have (for any new predicate $P'$) $A' \vdash (\forall x) [P'(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)]$. Hence $A \cup A' \vdash (\forall x) [P'(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)] \land (\forall x) [P'(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)]$, hence $A \cup A' \vdash (\forall x) [P(x) \leftrightarrow P'(x)]$.
>
> Beth's definability theorem says the converse - i.e. if $A$ implicitly defines $P$ from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$, then $A$ explicitly defines $P$ from $P_1, \ldots, P_n$.
>
> We shall prove Beth's theorem using Craig's lemma.

---

For a different approach, see :

- William Craig, [Logic in algebraic form : Three languages and theories](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0720422728) (1974), page 44.

See :

- René Cori & Daniel Lascar, [Mathematical Logic : A course with exercises. Part I : Propositional Calculus, Boolean Algebras, Predicate Calculus, Completeness Theorems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198500483) (English ed.2000; French ed.1993), page 42 :

for a proof of the *Interpolation lemma* and its use in the proof of the *Definability theorem* for propositional calculus.

For a more "easy" discussion of the issues regarding the treatment of defined symbols in first-order logic, see :

- George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521168465) (2003), **Ch.I.7. : Defined Symbols**, page 112-on

---

---

For a detailed discussion of the fact that

> Though deceptively simple and plausible on the face of it, Craig’s interpolation theorem has proved to be a central logical property that has been used to reveal a deep harmony between the syntax and semantics of first order logic.

see :

- Solomon Feferman, [Harmonious Logic : Craig’s Interpolation Theorem and its Descendants](http://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/Harmonious%20Logic.pdf) (2007)

Comment: According to the question's title and tag, the OP wants interpolation just for propositional logic, which makes it considerably easier than he first-order case in Shoenfield.

Comment: I'm not sure any of the following counts as "utility" but Daniele Mundici has proved some interesting results about the complexity of interpolation, treating both the propositional and first-order cases. Also, there's a proof of first-order interpolation that's based on the propositional interpolation theorem (plus a version of Herbrand's theorem). This is in Kreisel and Krivine's book "Elements de Logique Mathematique".